# Variance of sum calculation in example illustrating completeness for minimally sufficient statistic

Tags: variance, expected-value, likelihood, likelihood-ratio, sufficient-statistics

I have an example where it is said that $$\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i \sim N(n \mu, n a^2 \mu^2)$$ and

$$\begin{align} E \left[ \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i \right)^2 \right] &= \text{Var} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i \right) + \left[ E \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n \right) \right]^2 \\ &= na^2\mu^2 + n^2 \mu^2 = n(a^2 + n)\mu^2\end{align}$$

It seems that this implies that $\text{Var} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i \right) = na^2\mu^2$, which, if I'm not mistaken, is not in accordance with the [properties of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) (there should be a covariance in there somewhere?).

The full example is for the purpose of illustrating *completeness* in regards to **minimally sufficient statistics**:

> **Example 10**
>
> Let $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ be i.i.d. $N(\mu, a^2 \mu^2)$ and $a > 0$ is known.
>
> Such a model describes, for example, a series of measurements on an object using a measuring device whose accuracy is relative to the true (unknown) measure of the object rather than being constant.
>
> Show that $T(\mathbf{Y}) = (\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i, \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2)$ is
>
> - a minimally sufficient statistic for $\mu$ and
> - not a complete statistic.
>
> Take $\mathbf{y}_1$ and $\mathbf{y}_2$ be two sets of sample. The ratio of the likelihood is
>
> $$\begin{align} \dfrac{L(\mu; \mathbf{y}_1)}{L(\mu; \mathbf{y}_2)} = \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{(\sqrt{2 \pi a^2 \mu^2})^n} e^{-\dfrac{1}{2 a^2 \mu^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n (y_{1i} - \mu)^2}}{\dfrac{1}{(\sqrt{2 \pi a^2 \mu^2})^n} e^{-\dfrac{1}{2 a^2 \mu^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n (y_{2i} - \mu)^2}} &= e^{-\dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^n (y_{1i} - \mu)^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_{2i} - \mu)^2}{2a^2\mu^2}} \\ &= e^{-\dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^n y^2_{1i} - 2 \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{1i} \mu - \sum_{i = 1}^n y^2_{2i} + 2 \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{2i} \mu}{2 a^2 \mu^2}} \end{align}$$
>
> The ratio doesn't depend on $\mu$ if $\sum_{i = 1}^n y^2_{1i} = \sum_{i = 1}^n y^2_{2i}$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^n y_{1i} = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{2i}$. So $T(\mathbf{Y})$ is a minimal sufficient statistic.
>
> It is clear that $\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i \sim N(n \mu, n a^2 \mu^2)$. We have
>
> $$\begin{align} E \left[ \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i \right)^2 \right] &= \text{Var} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i \right) + \left[ E \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n \right) \right]^2 \\ &= na^2\mu^2 + n^2 \mu^2 = n(a^2 + n)\mu^2\end{align}$$
>
> $$\begin{align} E \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2 \right] &= \sum_{i = 1}^n E[Y^2_i] \\ &= \sum_{i = 1}^n \left( \text{Var}(Y_i) + E[Y_i]^2 \right) \\ &= n(a^2 + 1)\mu^2 \end{align}$$
>
> This implies that
>
> $$E \left[ \dfrac{a^2 + n}{a^2 + 1} \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2 - \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i \right)^2 \right] = 0$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify how $\text{Var} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i \right)$ is computed in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation for the normal distribution is $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. So if you have $\sum Y_i \sim N(n\mu, na^2\mu^2)$, the variance is equal to $na^2\mu^2$ by definition.

Comment: Oops, you’re right. I misinterpreted what the distribution was specified with regards to.